# Integromat - Google Calendar - How to add attachment to event with "Make an API call"

Tags: google-calendar-api, make.com

I would like to add attachment to Google calendar event with integromat "Make an API call" module. Attachment uploaded previously to Google drive.
I don't know how to setup the "MAKE an API call" module. See screenshot below.

[image: make an api call module integromat]

I tried to understand the integromat help for this, but it was a little bit difficult for me.
If somebody have a scenario for this please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that Google Calendar API doesn't support external files as part of the attachment, I might be wrong though. The current working scenario, that I shared will be able to add a Google Drive File as part of the attachment. Please refer the screenshot,

[image]

You will need to use following,

**URL**: /v3/calendars/{{CALENDAR_ID}}/events/{{EVENT_ID}}?supportsAttachments=true

**Method**: PATCH

**Body** :

```
{
    "attachments": [{
        "fileId" : "",
        "fileUrl": "https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yyVVQxgwb7wF6RckN_1KoGtSmikjk2MR/view?usp=sharing",
        "mimeType": "image/png",
        "title": "TestImage.png"
    }]
}
```

You can refer the document here : https://developers.google.com/calendar/api/v3/reference/events/patch

Comment: Thanks. It works with google drive files, and yes it doesnt work with external url files.